# How do I make an assertion that the value of a callback eventually changes?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, protractor, chai, chai-as-promised

I'm currently trying to write a test that asserts that after I click on an element the value of another element eventually changes. I tried the following :

```
it 'should change the value of the ec when the Scheduled option is clicked', ->
    element(By.css("li[title='Scheduled']")).click()
    expect(stateEc.getText()).to.eventually.equal("Scheduled")
```

The above test failed because the text of the stateEc element was "Ongoing" at the time of the expectations. I then added the following

```
 it 'should change the value of the ec when the Scheduled option is clicked', ->
    element(By.css("li[title='Scheduled']")).click()
    browser.wait( () ->
      return stateEc.getText().then (text) ->
        text is "Scheduled"
      , 2000)

    expect(stateEc.getText()).to.eventually.equal("Scheduled")
```

The test now passes every time - The problem is that I hate this solution and honestly thought that the very purpose of chai-as-promised was that I could create assertions that just had to become true within a certain time limit. What am I doing wrong?